# How to gather into rules

Tags: prolog, rule

What I would like to do is to return all the variables that I could obtain for an app. An app has extendable variables, I can extend them with some other variables, and non extendable variables.

My goal is to query `getvariables_for_app(web1)`, and get a simple flat (or complex) list of both extendable and non-extendable variables for the app.

```
% Not extendable variables
vartype(geocoordinate(latitude, longitude)).

% Extendable variables
vartype(street, location).
vartype(city, location).
vartype(housenumber, location).
vartype(postal_code, location).

% Extensions
extension(location, geocoordinate(latitude, longitude)).

% Variables per app
app(web1, street).
app(web1, city).
app(web1, housenumber).
app(web1, postal_code).
```

However, I'm not sure how to make this rule to obtain the list that I need.

```
getvariables_for_app(X) :- app(X, Y) ....
```

Update (what I have so far returns well, I just get 1 at a time):

```
getvariables_for_app(X,R) :- app(X, Y), vartype(Y, Z), extension(Z, R).
```

Expected output:

```
% order does not matter:
[geocoordinate(latitude, longitude), city, housenumber, postal_code, street]
```

Comment: Just use `findall/3` or `setof/3` (if you want the list unique and sorted).

Comment: @lurker I used `findall(X, getvariables_for_app(web1,R), X).` , but I get something I do not understand: `X = [_G4340, _G4337, _G4334, _G4331].`. What is going on?

Comment: @lurker I have no clue what I did, but this seems to be it: `setof(R, getvariables_for_app(web1,R), X).`

Comment: Your first attempt got the variables mixed up. The first variable should be the variable in the query: `findall(R, getvariables_for_app(web1, R), X)`.  You used `X` as the first argument. You got it right when you did `setof/3`, your `R` is the query variable in that case.

Comment: @lurker Thanks, it certainly is an improvement, but how do I still get "Y" (the extendable variables) to also be in there?

Comment: Unclear what you mean. Your `getvariables_for_app/2` already handles `Y` internally.

Comment: @lurker It handles it, but it does not output it into the list of results?

Comment: @lurker Ah, I see, it is in its own variable Y, "logically".

Comment: If you're still stuck somewhere, perhaps you could, in your problem statement, give an example of what kind of output you want.

Comment: @lurker Yea I kind of got I wanted, just by having Y separated out though. Expected output would be everything included in one list, rather than a separate Y when calling `setof(R, getvariables_for_app(web1, R, Y), X).`

Comment: If you want to capture `R` and `Y`, you'll need a term for it, *e.g.*, `setof((R,Y), getvariables_for_app(web1, R, Y), X)`, or something like that.